# How to deploy Github action pipeline with multiple branches in same YAML file using IF condition

Tags: github, yaml, azure-pipelines, github-actions, cicd

I am going to setup github action pipeline to deploy code into server via azure CLI and azure run command.

Here i have many branches in same repository and i need to deploy the code to corresponding server for each branch

eg. repo if push branch1 --> deploy in server 1
if push branch2 --> deploy in server 2

So if i push to branch1 that should deploy in server1 and same as for all servers

For this i created YAML file using if condition but i don't know whether it  will work or not.
I referred many document but cannot get the solution for this scenario

Here is my YAML file

```
name: deploy
on:
  push:
      branches: [ branch1, branch2, branch3 ]

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14.x
      - name: Log in with Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: '${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}'
      if: ${{ push.branches == 'branch1' }}
      - name: 'Run az commands'
        run: |
           az list vm
      if: ${{ push.branches == 'branch2' }}
      - name: 'Run az commands'
        run: |
           az list vm
      if: ${{ push.branches == 'branch3' }}
      - name: 'Run az commands'
        run: |
           az list vm
```

Can anyone please guide me how to configure yaml file for this scenario?

Comment: You should carefully evaluate your branching model; the way you are using branches right now is a *very* bad practice.

Comment: I know its wrong i don't know the exact conditional statement to check the condition. That's why raise the question in flow. Still searching for the proper conditional statement and syntax to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I build my YAML file with proper steps. "github.ref == 'value'" is the syntax for check the branch. Below i mentioned my simplified code for reference if anyone wants same logic.

As per @David Slutsky syntax also works.

```
name: FFR-deploy
on:
  push:
      branches: [ Azure-pipeline, Azure-pipeline-devops ]

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
                
      - name: Log in with Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: '${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}'
      
      - name: 'Run on azure-pipeline branch'
        if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/Azure-pipeline' }}
        run: |
         az list vm
      
      - name: 'Run on azure-pipeline-devops branch'
        if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/Azure-pipeline-devops' }}
        run: |
         az list vm
```

Answer (score 3):

Should work

```yaml
name: deploy
on:
  push:
      branches: [ branch1, branch2, branch3 ]

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14.x
      - name: Log in with Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: '${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}'
      - name: 'Run az commands on branch 1'
        if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/branch1' }}
        run: |
           az list vm
      - name: 'Run az commands on branch 2'
        if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/branch2' }}
        run: |
           az list vm
      - name: 'Run az commands on branch 3'
        if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/branch3' }}
        run: |
           az list vm
```

Comment: The syntax is correct but conditional statement is wrong to check the branch. once modified proper conditional statement will let know in the comment. thanks for your time!

Comment: @jayaprakashR probably you're looking for [github.ref](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context). Use Ctrl+F to find this "variable".